# What is the relationship among the various algorithms?

Tags: algorithms

I'm curious about whether there exists a hierarchical or layered concept within the broad categories of algorithms, where they can be further divided into subcategories based on their characteristics and problem-solving approaches. Is there a clear association or inheritance relationship between different algorithm categories or subcategories? For instance, are some algorithms based on the same fundamental principles but optimized for different application scenarios? How to define them?

I aim to understand the underlying patterns or classes of relationships that have emerged among these algorithms. In other words, I'm looking to explore the types or categories of relationships between algorithms that naturally evolved from their original intent to solve problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a handy categorization from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm#Classification) and a list of few popular [algorithmic topics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms).